# What is the difference between SpanQuery and PhraseQuery?

Tags: solr, lucene

Suppose I would like to search index with 2 term query.
I can do it with `PhraseQuery(term1, term2, slop = 2) or with SpanNearQuery(term1, term2, slop=2, ordered=false)`. 
What is the difference in lucene scoring for these configurations?

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my understanding, a phrase query with slop will tokenize the phrase, then apply the slop distance between each token, whereas in a span query a phrase will be retained as a unit.

So if you have a phrase query for `"cat dog bird"` with slop `3`, it'd match `cat horse lizard dog bird`.

But a span query for `"cat dog" bird` with slop `3` would not match `cat horse lizard dog bird` because `cat` and `dog` are not adjacent. It would, however, match: `cat dog horse lizard bird`.